# CPP access violation Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I keep getting this Error: **access violation at 0x40496a: write of address 0x0.** I'm using Borland C++.

This is my source code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *nm;
    cout<<"\n Enter a name: ";
    gets(nm);
    cout<<"\n Name: "<<nm;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Even if I set char *nm=NULL or use cin>> for input I'm getting the same error. Please Help, Thanks.

Comment: You did not allocate any memory, just a pointer to nothing

Comment: but i just want get input from user... if I write     nm=new char[20]; will it be correct? or is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: `char nm[100];`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `nm` you don't initialize it, that means the value of `nm` is indeterminate, it doesn't really point anywhere (in reality it points to a seemingly random location). You need to make it point to something big enough to hold the string you input.

Using uninitialized variables, and `NULL` pointers, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) whose most common result is a crash.

To fix this, either make it point to an already initialized array:

```
char str[20];
char* nm = str;
```

Or allocate memory for the string dynamically:

```
char* nm = new char[20];
```

Or even better, don't use character pointers as string, and *especially* ***not*** the `gets` function (it's dangerous and have even been removed from the C standard), use the C++ [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class instead and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function to fetch a line:

```
std::string nm;
std::getline(std::cin, nm);
```

Or if you just want to get a single space-delimited word, use the normal input operator:

```
std::string nm;
std::cin >> nm;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood what was the mistake, I just on more confusion, what is meaning of std::string nm; I think it means string belongs to std class ? I'm getting confused because I have never used this syntax. please help

Comment: @PramodGupta [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232) is a nice place to start with.

Comment: @PramodGupta It's probably because you use such an old version of C++ (I'm guessing you are using TurboC++?). Quite a lot have happened with the C++ language and its runtime library in the last 20 or so years, which means that unfortunately all you are learning at school with TurboC++ already is useless for use in the real world.

Comment: @PramodGupta My advice is for you to continue your schoolwork with TurboC++, but if you really want to learn C++ then you should install e.g. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) or some other free modern environment, and follow the link in P0Ws comment for some better tutorials and references, and work on those at home.